# run pdp.pdp_plot for multiple features and put output axes to new figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, axes

Is there a way to plot multiple features using `pdp.pdp_plot` function from the PDPbox python package? The python package is PDPbox https://pdpbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Currently, as I understand, the function can generate a plot for individual features and returns matplotlib figure and axis. It is hard to manage individual axis and assign them a new figure and compile all the axes into a figure.

edit:
Looks like it's not possible to plot multiple features simultaneously. Has someone figured out a way to extract the axis from `pdp.pdp_plot` function and put it in another figure along with other axes?

According to the documentation: https://pdpbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pdp_plot.html
The function returns `fig: matplotlib Figure` and `axes: a dictionary of matplotlib Axes`

How can I run the function for multiple features, save axes objects, and put all of them together in one figure?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only use the pdp.pdp_plot method to plot the partial dependent plot for one feature (documentation: https://pdpbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pdp_plot.html)